# Python - SQL ODBC login with active directory authentication using user name & password

Tags: python, linux, pyodbc

Is there a way to login to SQL server from Linux server using "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server" by passing active directory UID & PWD (not using Trusted_Connection=Yes option).

I tried with below connection parameters but getting error:

1. "Driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;MultiSubnetFailover=Yes;UID=;PWD=;Server=;Database=;"
   Error: Login failed
2. "Driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;MultiSubnetFailover=Yes;UID=;PWD=;Server=;Database=;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword";

   Error: SSL Provider: SSL routines: [error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed: self signed certificate]

Is there a way to get achieve this?